# How to use pip cache when deploying using CDK?

Tags: python, aws-cdk

Whenever I run `cdk deploy`, messages like this one shows up (shown in context):

```
Bundling asset api/import_status/user-import_status-endpoint-function/Code/Stage...
WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
```

Is this an actual problem? If so, how do I work around it? CDK builds do seem very slow, and this message shows up all over the place when people mention CDK (although I couldn't find anyone asking this specific question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by using effectively `--cache-dir="$(mktemp --directory)"`.

Comment: This response is really clean! Perfect setting builds inside docker container.